# Conditional define in a compiler directive?

Tags: delphi, embedded-resource

Can a conditional define like `$(Config)` be used in compiler directives?

For example:

```
{$R Payload.res Resources\THE_DEFINE\ResTHE_DEFINE.rc}
```

Comment: One nitpick: `$(Config)` refers the environment variable `Config`, it is not a conditional define. I don't think you could use `' %config%\resthe_define.rc'`, but you can try.

Comment: @Rudy Velthuis: A conditional define could easily be made out of it. I have put `brcc32` with `$(Config)` into pre-build action as David suggested.

Comment: no, it could not, as it is an environment variable. That works fine in a pre-build action, but not in (Delphi) source code.

Comment: I don't have a "Defines" in "Project Options". So what exactly did you mean?

Comment: `Project` > `Options` > `Delphi Compiler` > `Conditional defines` = $(Config)

Comment: So then you have a conditional define named $(config). How are you using that in the $R directive?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Can a conditional define like `$(Config)` be used in compiler directives?

The simple answer is no it cannot.

If I were trying to compile and link a resource conditionally, I would do so using an external build script invoked from a pre-build action.